# Default Option and returning NULL

Tags: php

Trying to figure out how to better write this chunk of code. I'm wanting to get the list of the roster members and then create an array of options for the view dropdown to display inside the select dropdown and also have it have an option to display "Please Select An Option". However what if what is returned from the getAllRoster function is NULL which is what I have returned if no results are returned from a query. How should I handle that which I just want the empty option displayed.

Also I need to think about is do a function to retrieve all the allies for that specific matter and then display that ally as the default ally in the dropdown for each dropdown.

Controller:

```
$rosterList = $this->bios->getAllRoster();
$allies = array();
$allies[''] = 'Please Select An Opion';
foreach ($rosterList AS $ally)
{
    $allies[$ally->id] = $ally->rosterName;
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo form_label( 'Ally 1', 'ally1'); ?>
    <div>
    <?php echo form_dropdown( 'ally1', $allies, ''); ?>
</div>
<?php echo form_label( 'Ally 2', 'ally2'); ?>
    <div>
    <?php echo form_dropdown( 'ally2', $allies, ''); ?>
</div>
<?php echo form_label( 'Ally 3', 'ally3'); ?>
    <div>
    <?php echo form_dropdown( 'ally3', $allies, ''); ?>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

What I am wanting to do is if the allies array is empty it needs to display the message No wrestlers in database but its instead giving me an error in my view file.

Controller:
[pastebin.com/1Bf721zJ](http://pastebin.com/1Bf721zJ)

View:

```
<?php echo form_label( 'Ally 1', 'ally1'); ?>
<div>
        <?php if ($allies[''] == 'No Wrestlers In Database') {
            echo $allies[''];
        }
        else {
            echo form_dropdown( 'ally1', $allies, '');
        } ?>
    </div>
```

I also am curious about something. I have the alliesList variable that either has a value of a resultset or null and what I want to do if its a result set is have each of the allies be the default value in each of the dropdowns.

Comment: you realise you can echo the <div> and </div>s right? its messy with all those php tags

Comment: Yes but I'm the type to keep html as it is unless I need it dynamically created like inside a loop or something.

Comment: @user1333299 Whether you echo it or not, PHP is going to read the whole page, compile the PHP parts, and then return a pure HTML page. Sort-of dynamic if you ask me.

Comment: Any ideas on the actually question I asked though

Comment: You're capturing the return value from getAllRoster in a variable but then not using that variable at all in your code snippet. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah that's not right but still lost.

Comment: The divs aren't even necessary in this case, they hold no ids, classes, names, they serve no purpose in their current form, your code would look the same with or without them. As for your code, they are all function calls, kinda hard to tell you a better way to do something when there's nothing to look at.

Comment: They are important due to the structure of my page because of the template.

Comment: @showerhead I'm using psuedoclasses and has css rules attached to those divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$rosterList = $this->bios->getAllRoster();
$allies = array();

if (empty($rosterList) {
    $allies[] = 'nothing to display';
}
 else
{
    $allies[] = 'Please Select An Option';
    foreach ($rosterList AS $ally)
    {
        $allies[$ally->id] = $ally->rosterName;
    }
}
```

also in your view, if you don't want to display a drop down you could put a conditional in to display something else, e.g.:

```
 <?php if ($allies[0] == 'nothing to display') {
echo $allies[0]
}
else {
  echo form_dropdown( 'ally1', $allies, '');
} ?>
```

Comment: Very nice! However what about the second part of my question. What I need to do is do a function to retrieve the member's allies and then somehow tie in those to each of the dropdowns in the correct order meaning if ally1 in the db has a value of 1 then it displays the option with that id that has a matching value.

Comment: If you just want to display a default value, from the list you already have, check out the documentation. But if you mean, you want to display three different lists, you need to think a bit harder about how you select your $allies. Or phrase the question again, in a way that is easier to understand.

Comment: Actually when I do this it gives me undefined variable allies in the view.

Comment: I've looked at the pastebin and I still don't understand what you need to do. How about trying to explain it?

Comment: Well it needs to list the allies for each dropdown and if not it needs to display that nothing to display message

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure i fully understand your question but if im right cant you just do

```
if $_GET['allies'] == "Please select an option"{
    $something = Null
}
else{
    $something = $_GET['allies']
}
```

and use `$something` where you would have used `$_GET['allies']`?

Comment: I have never used codeIgnighter so i dont know how that is relevant